# How to find the center of an object using Rotate Copies in Sketch 3?

Tags: sketch-app

### How can I tell where the center of an object is?

How can I display the center of an object using [Rotate Copies](http://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/04-shapes/6-rotate-copies.html)?

### Example

Where is the center of the orange oval?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach is simple. I create a vertical and a horizontal [Guide](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/10-canvas/2-rulers-guides-grids.html) for the object in question. Then when using the Rotate Copies tool, I simply target the intersection of the red Guides.